# Why is let not a valid recur target?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, this is valid:

```
(loop [a 5]
  (if (= a 0)
    "done"
    (recur (dec a))))
```

However, this is not:

```
(let [a 5]
  (if (= a 0)
    "done"
    (recur (dec a))))
```

So I'm wondering: why are loop and let separated, given the fact they both (at least conceptually) introduce lexical bindings? That is, why is loop a recur target while let is not?

EDIT: originally wrote "loop target" which I noticed is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
(defn pascal-step [v n]
  (if (pos? n)
      (let [l (concat v [0])
            r (cons 0 v)]
        (recur (map + l r) (dec n)))
      v))
```

This function calculates `n+m`th line of pascal triangle by given `m`th line.

Now, imagine, that `let` is a `recur` target. In this case I won't be able to recursively call the `pascal-step` function itself from `let` binding using `recur` operator.

Now let's make this example a little bit more complex:

```
(defn pascal-line [n]
  (loop [v [1]
         i n]
    (if (pos? i)
        (let [l (concat v [0])
              r (cons 0 v)]
          (recur (map + l r) (dec i)))
        v)))
```

Now we're calculating `n`th line of a pascal triangle. As you can see, I need both `loop` and `let` here.

This example is quite simple, so you may suggest removing `let` binding by using `(concat v [0])` and `(cons 0 v)` directly, but I'm just showing you the concept. There may be a more complex examples where `let` inside a `loop` is unavoidable.

Comment: Ok I see your point. However, why then doesn't recur have an extra optional arg that specifies which target to jump to? Or would that go too much in the direction of goto's (and we all know what Dijkstra said about gotos)?

Comment: @jjpe let is not a recur target because loop is. If let was a recur target, loop would not exist. loop is exactly the same as let, except that it also acts as a recur target. See http://clojure.org/special_forms#loop